# Matlab ode45 help undefined variable

Tags: matlab, ode, ode45

```
function yp = nonlinear (t,y)
e=0.2;
yp(1)=y(2);
yp(2) = (-y(1)-e*y(1)^3);
tspan = [0.20];
y0=[0;0]
[t,y]=ode45('nonlinear',tpsan,y0)
plot (t,y(:,1))
grid
xlabel('time')
ylabel('u')
title ('u vs. t')
hold on;
```

Sorry I am absolutely noob at matlab, when I try to execute the code, it says "undefined function of variable t". I am trying to use ode45 to solve a differential equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [documentation on `ode45`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html). You need to save the following lines of your code into a file `nonlinear.m`

```
function yp = nonlinear (t,y)
e=0.2;
yp(1)=y(2);
yp(2) = (-y(1)-e*y(1)^3);
```

and then in a separate (script) file, save the rest of your code:

```
tspan = [0.20];
y0=[0;0]
[t,y]=ode45('nonlinear',tpsan,y0)
plot (t,y(:,1))
grid
xlabel('time')
ylabel('u')
title ('u vs. t')
hold on;
```

You might also want to familiarise yourself with MATLAB before attempting that sort of thing. Check out the [tutorials](https://uk.mathworks.com/support/learn-with-matlab-tutorials.html).

Comment: Or close the function definition with an `end` if one wants to avoid multiple files.